# How to configure nginx for unqualified host names?

Tags: nginx

I am setting up nginx as a reverse proxy. I have only used Apache before, and without virtual hosts.

I want my users to be able to access various intranet web services by simply typing the name of the service into the address bar. E.g. to type "timesheets" rather than "timesheets.intranet.local".

On a client machine if I use "wget" or a browser to access the FQDN for the site (timesheets.intranet.local) then everything is fine.

On a client machine if I use "wget" or a browser to access the plain hostname for the site (timesheets) then it fails.

If I use "wget" locally on the nginx server machine then both work fine.

My site config looks like:

```
server {
  server_name timesheets timesheets.intranet.local;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  }

  listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /root/timesheet.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /root/timesheet.key;
}
```

Name resolution is not the problem. "wget" on the client machine correctly resolves the IP address but still fails to retrieve the page.

Comment: Are you saying that ping, nslookup and wget work correctly on the user's machine?

Comment: Do you want it to be `timesheet` or "timesheets"? You've specified one in the nginx configuration and the other in your narrative. Maybe you should set up both.

Comment: @RSmith On the user's machine, ping, nslookup, and wget all report the correct IP address for the host. wget does not work on the users machine but does work on the server itself.

Comment: @MHampton, It's a typo.

Comment: Maybe a ping and so on work because of some different resolution method, not DNS (i.e. NetBIOS or something other like that)? Then web browser might not support this resolution method and will not work. Try adding said unqualified names to hosts file explicitely.

Comment: Let me clarify: When running wget on the "user machine", wget tries the correct IP address but fails to load the page. Hence DEFINITELY NOT a name resolution problem because it is failing when trying the correct ip address!

Comment: And what's on  port 8080? Could it be a culprit? What exactly says wget? What says curl? What is in nginx logs? What is in logs of that thing on port 8080?

Comment: Port 8080 is my docker container. The whole system works perfectly if you use the FQDN (as stated in the question). I think the problem is because nginx is not correctly matching the host (timesheets) in the GET request to the plain server name in the nginx config, but does match the FQDN (timesheets.intranet.local).

Comment: Probably it's not nginx doesn't match a host, but it forwards a short Host header further and the thing in your Docker container doens't want (isn't configured) to service an unqualified name?

Comment: That's it! I removed the ServerName directive from the Apache config in the container and now it gets through! Please post that as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When configuring reverse proxying you must pay attention not only to a proxy configuration, but also consider a configuration of a service behind it.

Not only the proxy must accept a name in its virtualhost, but it must also issue a Host header which is expected to the backend. In this case easiest way is to configure both proxy and a backend to accept a short unqualified host name.

Alternate way might be to override which Host header proxy is sending to a backend. Then you only need your backend to server only that hostname. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352690/change-host-header-in-nginx-reverse-proxy